# Is it possible to enforce all links of one domain to open in a defined tab (in chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As more and more web-apps are used in daily work life, I would like to reduce the effort managing all the open tabs. However, the web isn't making my life easy, it tends to open more and more tabs over the day.

A browser-plugin or similar technique could help here, if technical feasible.

Let's assume the following scenario. I have 3 apps always open in (pinned) tabs:

- Mail (mail.google.com)
- Calendar (calendar.google.com)
- Task-List (app.asana.com)

Now if I click a link to a task which someone send by mail or which was mentioned in a calendar event, I end op with:

- Mail (mail.google.com)
- Calendar (calendar.google.com)
- Task-List (app.asana.com)
- Task-List (app.asana.com/task-id)

What I want to achieve is to open in the tab 3 automatically, e.g. defined by the domain. So that I click in calendar a link and get to:

- Mail (mail.google.com)
- Calendar (calendar.google.com)
- Task-List (app.asana.com/task-id)

Is it technically possible to write a browser extension to handle this? Could this also handle linkes opened externally from another application on the system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using `chrome.tabs.onCreated`, `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.scripting.executeScript`.

it follows something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
 if(tab.url == "your_url"){       //use regex match if needed
  var toBeOpenedUrl = tab.url;
  var newTabId = tab.id; //store this tabId to close
  chrome.tabs.query({url: "your_url"}, function(tabs){
   var tabId = tabs[0].id //assuming 1st tab that match the url is where you want to open.
   function openUrl() {
    window.location.url = toBeOpenedUrl;
   }
   chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tabId},
      func: openUrl,
   }, function(){
     //close the newTab by injecting window.close into the newTabId as a function
   });
  }
 }
}
```

Note that it will create the tab and close, if you do not want that you need to fiddle around with `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`.

Comment: Where do you run this? In an add-on?

Comment: this is for chrome extension. These code come at background script of chrome extension.

Comment: did you find a finalized solution?